# IN and = operator in JPA query language

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have a problem regarding jpa query. 
There are two tables i.e. Post table and Tag table
There is many to many relationship between Post and Tag

Now I want to write a query such that when multiple tags are chosen then all the posts associated with those tags should be selected.
For example,

```
post1 has tags friends and motivation
post2 has tags motivation and pune
post3 has tag boxing
```

if tags friends and pune are chosen then post1 and post 2 should be retrieved
if tag boxing is chosen then only post 3 should be retrieved
if tags boxing and motivation are chosen then all three posts should be retrieved.

I tried following things

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tags WHERE p.tags IN :tags
```

but it gives validator error that

```
The state field path 'p.tags' cannot be resolved to a collection type.
```

If I try like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tags WHERE p.tags = :tags
```

then it complies fine but after passing a list of tags it gives error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter tags with expected type of class com.justme.model.entities.Tag from query string SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tags WHERE p.tags = :tags.
```

Thank you for reading this much :) can you please guide me on this?

how can I achieve the results mentioned above?
my persistence provider is eclipseLink

This is Post entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Post.selectAllPosts", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.dateCreated DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Post.selectPostForUser", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.user = :user ORDER BY p.dateCreated DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Post.selectPostsByTags", query = "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tags WHERE p.tags IN :tags") })
public class Post implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idpost;

@Lob
private String content;

private String title;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to User
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "iduser")
private User user;

// bi-directional many-to-many association to Tag
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "post_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idpost"),         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idtag"))
private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date = null;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreated = new Date();

public Post() {
}

public int getIdpost() {
    return this.idpost;
}

public void setIdpost(int idpost) {
    this.idpost = idpost;
}

public String getContent() {
    return this.content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return this.tags;
}

public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Post [idpost=" + idpost + ", content=" + content + ", title="
            + title + ", date=" + date + "]";
}

}
```

This is Tag Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Tag.selectTags", query = "SELECT tag FROM Tag tag WHERE tag.tagName LIKE :keyword"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Tag.selectMatchingTags", query = "SELECT t.tagName FROM Tag t WHERE t.tagName LIKE :keyword"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Tag.selectTagByName", query = "SELECT tag FROM Tag tag WHERE tag.tagName = :tagName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Tag.selectTagsForAllPosts", query = "SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM Tag tag, Post post JOIN tag.posts posts WHERE post.user = :user")})

public class Tag implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idtag;

private String tagName;

// bi-directional many-to-many association to Post
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Post> posts;


public Tag() {

}

public Tag(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName;
}


public int getIdtag() {
    return this.idtag;
}

public void setIdtag(int idtag) {
    this.idtag = idtag;
}

public String getTagName() {
    return this.tagName;
}

public void setTagName(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName;
}

public List<Post> getPosts() {
    return this.posts;
}

public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return tagName;
}

}
```

Comment: can you please post the code of your Post entity? Looks like the issue may be there

Comment: @kostja Added entity code as per your suggestions.
and you can notice that the NamedQuery Tag.selectTagForAllPosts which retrieved all tags for the user works just fine. I think retrieving tags from posts should also be similar thats why I tried above thing but it does not work

Comment: I think this simplified version could work: `SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p WHERE p.tags IN :tags`

Comment: @kostja thank you for answer but when I wrote the query you gave to me, it again shows validation error as mentioned above

    The state field path 'p.tags' cannot be resolved to a collection type.

Comment: Then Im effectively clueless, the query and the entities looks right to me, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @kostja what are you saying man? You are absolutely not wasting my time. I would like to thank you for your time

Comment: Try "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tag WHERE tag IN :tags". You want a single tag from p.tags used to compare against the collection parameter.

Comment: What version of EclipseLink are you using?  Try one of the latest as yours might not support passing in a collection to IN

Comment: @Chris I don't want a single tag to be selected. As described above, I want all the posts which are tagged by the collection I pass.

and as you suggested, I switched to eclipseLink 2.4 from eclipseLink 2.1 but of no use :(

Comment: @Chris Can you please tell me why path expression error comes if I use IN operator and it disappears if I use '=' operator in the WHERE clause? This is described in detail in the question

Comment: You don't want all tags, you want posts that have any tag in the list you pass in.  Using '=' is a non-issue - it cannot work.  The p.tags does not represent a collection in the database, it represents a join to a table, which will result in there being many rows for a single p entity, one for each tag reference.  The error indicates EclipseLink is interpreting p.tags to be IN(p.tags) for you, but it isn't strict JPQL.  Try breaking your collection parameter up so that it looks like "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tags WHERE tags IN (:tag1, :tag2)", get that working, then try a list

Comment: @Chris thanks man for the useful information :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
    ...
    @NamedQuery(name = "Post.selectPostsByTags", query =
       "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p JOIN p.tags tags WHERE tags IN (:tags)") })
public class Post implements Serializable {
    ...
```

Use it like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager em;
...
List<Tag> ltags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
ltags.add(tagOne);
ltags.add(tagTwo);
List<?> list = em.createNamedQuery("Post.selectPostsByTags")
                                                    .setParameter("tags", ltags)
                                                    .getResultList();

for (Object object : list) {
    System.out.println("Results: "+object);
}
```

Comment: actually I am not able to find getNamedQuery method at all, and I suppose the session object you are referring to is of type EntityManager. 
Also, I could not find setParameterList method on createNamedQuery.

Am I right or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: Actually, `setParameterList` works on Hibernate. I edited the answer. Should work as expected (in Eclipselink) now.

Comment: hey man... that was a great help. It worked. 
actually I still had to replace IN (:tags) with IN :tags. 
I don't understand why does it cause problems.

Also, I was wrong at writing p.tags in WHERE clause instead of tags.
Can you please explain me what is the difference? 
Can you please suggest a good tutorial which explains JPA query language syntax very well :) 
thank you for the help.
I will vote up as soon as I become eligible

Comment: guys, what if i want ALL tags in passed collection to be match? is it possible with JPA?